# How to hook into express session creation event

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

How can I tell when express creates a new session? I'm using a mongodb session store.

I'm having an issue with extra sessions being created, and want to narrow down on the problem by tracking which urls requests are triggering new sessions to be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.returning) {
        // session was just created
        req.session.returning = true
    } else {
        // old session
    }
    next()
})
```

Comment: I can't find `returning` anywhere in the code of https://github.com/expressjs/express and https://github.com/expressjs/session. I'm not sure if you should (still) rely on this method

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek we're setting that property on the session ourselves, you could call it whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the `genid` callback. By default `express-session` generates its own session IDs.

But you can generate the session ID yourself by specifying a `genid` callback. Within this callback you can log that a new session is being created (and then return a unique session ID).

Here is an example, adapted from the `express-session` README:

```
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    console.log('New session was created');
    return genuuid(); // generate a UUID somehow and return it
  },
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer, but leads me to a followup/better question: Is there a way to tell if the req.session object was just recently created, or was retrieved from the store?

Comment: For anyone trying to use this, the session has not been created at this point, so you can't do anything with it. You can't access it with `this` or `req.session`, both are `undefined.` I know this answer is 7 years old, but it the top result on Google.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Nate is fine. I'm answering because of 2 additions I'd like to make.

1. In case you also want the kind of sessionID that [express-session would otherwise generate](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/a8bda70b34abc31fd957321b567855407ee8d607/index.js#L292-L294). You can do this:

```
const uid = require('uid-safe').sync;
//...

    genid: function(req) {
        console.log('New session was created');
        // do what you want to do here!
        return uid(24); // <-- the way express-session generates it
    },
```

2. Be aware that you cannot use an `async` function for genid. Express-session calls this function without `await`, so that would get a promise instead of the uid.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this, the session has not been created at this point, so you can't do anything with it. You can't access it with `this` or `req.session`, both are `undefined.` I know this answer is 3 years old, but it the top result on Google.